# What's the use case of glTexParameterIiv and glTexParameterIuiv?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

The [OpenGL documentation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glTexParameter.xml) says very little about these two functions. When it would make sense to use `glTexParameterIiv` instead of `glTexParameteriv` or even `glTexParameterfv`?

> If the values for GL_TEXTURE_BORDER_COLOR are specified with glTexParameterIiv or glTexParameterIuiv, the values are stored unmodified with an internal data type of integer. If specified with glTexParameteriv, they are converted to floating point with the following equation: *f=(2c+1)/(2<sup>b</sup>−1)*. If specified with glTexParameterfv, they are stored unmodified as floating-point values.

Comment: I had to reformat your pasted text, the equation came out wrong. But basically what `f=(2c+1)/(2^b-1)` does is take a *signed* integer value `(c)` and normalize it to the range [**-1**,**1**], where `(b)` is the number of bits per-component. My answer discusses normalization for unsigned colors (which is the more typical scenario).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sort of answered your own question with the snippet you pasted. Traditional textures are fixed-point (unsigned normalized, where values like **255** are converted to **1.0** through normalization), but GL 3.0 introduced integral (signed / unsigned integer) texture types (where integer values stay integers).

If you had an integer texture and wanted to assign a border color (for use with the `GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER` wrap mode), you would use one variant of those two functions (depending on whether you want signed or unsigned).

You cannot filter integer textures, but you can still have texture coordinate wrap behavior. Since said textures are integer and `glTexParameteriv (...)` normalizes the color values it is passed, an extra function had to be created to keep the color data integer.

You will find this same sort of thing with `glVertexAttribIPointer (...)` and so forth; adding support for integer data (as opposed to simply converting integer data to floating-point) to the GL pipeline required a lot of new commands.

Comment: And what exactly is gained by not converting the integers? Is it only a matter of avoiding the normalization cost or keeping data integral is a good idea, for example, if I need to do more computation on these colors later?

Comment: @philix: Some algorithms actually need integer values. If you want a 1 dimensional lookup table that can represent 4.27 billion different integer values you would use `GL_R32UI` as your texture's internal format. You could not actually accomplish that with a 32-bit floating-point texture, because after you exhaust the floating-point mantissa (2^24) you can no longer precisely represent integer values in floating-point. The [matlab explanation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flintmax.html) is pretty nice.

Comment: Yes, I understand that problem. Since I don't have much experience with OpenGL I hadn't got to the point of doing anything with the data in the texture after I pass it to OpenGL. As I see it there's no much sense in using `glTexParameter[u]iv` to set `GL_TEXTURE_BORDER_COLOR` in OpenGL 3.0. One should probably use `glTexParameterfv` or `glTexParameterI[u]iv`. Is that correct?

Comment: @philix: `GL_TEXTURE_BORDER_COLOR` is not the best example for this sort of thing. Texture borders are rarely used in real-world scenarios (the only use I can think of is defining an out-of-bounds depth value for shadow maps). The thing you have to understand about `I` (and in newer versions of GL, `L` -- double-precision floating-point) variants of GL functions is that they require special data formats. You will know when it is appropriate to use the `I` function variant because you are trying to store data as an integer instead of floating-point. Your shader would use `ivec4` for example.